# Extra indentation for argument lists beginning on a new line

Tags: indentation, c++, style

I'm fine-tuning my C++ style using `c-add-style`, but I've reached an impasse where I cannot convince Emacs to (extra) indent arguments where the first argument starts on a new line.

When I'm forced to start argument lists on a new line I prefer to indent the arguments an extra level to distinguish them from the function body:

```
void particularlyLongFunctionName(
        particularlyLongTypeName &particularlyLongArgumentName) {
    foo(particularlyLongArgumentName);
    bar();
}
```

My configuration, on the other hand, indents the argument list no more than the following code block:

```
void particularlyLongFunctionName(
    particularlyLongTypeName &particularlyLongArgumentName) {
    foo(particularlyLongArgumentName);
    bar();
}
```

Which field in the `c-style-alist` controls this setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set point on the line in question and press `C-c C-s` to call `c-show-syntactic-information`. This shows you which variable you need to set.

I set this to:

```
(c-offsets-alist . (
    (arglist-intro . c-lineup-arglist-intro-after-paren))) ;; first parameter after open paren
```

which is not quite that what you want, but instead of `c-lineup-arglist-intro-after-paren` you could use `++`.

Test another offset with `C-c C-o` (which calls `c-set-offset`).

Also have a look at the [cc-mode manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/) and more concrete at the [c-offset-alist docu node](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html#c_002doffsets_002dalist). Or at the [Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC).

Comment: This is great! But if I associate arglist-intro with + I get the same behavior that I started out with. @jue

Comment: @Caterpillar use `++`